# Time issue with ZMQ Recv and recv_string

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, time, zeromq, pyzmq

this code I use below is a ZMQ sub to a publisher that is giving me data. It uses the counter to tell me when its 30 and 59 seconds to run my write to CSV every 30 seconds or so.

Problem: I am now timing all of the processes in my thread. the lines where message and message2 = socket.recv_string() is taking anywhere from half a second to 20 seconds to receive string. Thus causing the thread to miss the 30 and 59 second intervals I set. This was not happening yesterday. The other timers for the if statements are taking .00001 or 0.0 seconds. So that part isnt the problem

Im wondering what could effect this. Could it be the processing power of my computer? Or is the receive string based on how long it waits for the publisher to actually send something?

I'm not running in a dev or production environment and its on a shared server with something like 15 other people and its virtual. A zero client. I've never had this problem before and on another script i have set up for another ZMQ pub/sub I'm receiving messages in .01 or .001 seconds all the way to 3 seconds. Which is more manageable but the norm was .01.

Any tips or help would be amazing. Thanks in advance

```
import zmq
import pandas as pd
import time
import threading



df_fills = pd.DataFrame()
df_signal = pd.DataFrame()
second_v = [30,59]
s = 0
m = 0
h = 0
d = 0

def counter():
    global h,s,m,d
    while True:
        s += 1
        #print("Second:{}".format(s))
        if s >=60:
            m +=1
            s = 0
        if m >= 60:
            h += 1
            m = 0
        if h >= 24:
            d += 1
            h = 0     
        #print(s)
        time.sleep(1)


class zmq_thread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,name):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.name = name
    def run(self):  
        global df_fills, second_v,s 
        print('zmq started')
        context = zmq.Context()
        socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)              
        socket.connect(SERVER)        
        socket.setsockopt_string(zmq.SUBSCRIBE,'F')            
        print('socket connected')     
        tickers = [a bunch of tickers] 
        while True:                                 
            try:
                start2 = time.time()                               
                if s == 30:
                    print('break')
                    if df_fills.empty == True:
                       print('running fill thread again')
                       z = zmq_thread('Start_ZMQ') 
                       #time.sleep(.7)
                       z.run()  
                    else:
                        start = time.time()
                        print('writing fills')
                        filename = "a CSV"
                        with open(filename, 'a') as f:
                            df_fills.to_csv(f, encoding = 'utf-8', index = False, header = False)
                            f.close()     
                            print('wrote fills')                                          
                            end = time.time()
                            print(end-start)
                            df_fills = df_fills.iloc[0:0]                    
                            z = zmq_thread('Start_ZMQ') 
                            z.run()                    
                    return df_fills     
                end2 = time.time()
                print(end2-start2) 
                start3 = time.time()
                message = socket.recv_string()
                message2 = socket.recv_string()  
                end3 = time.time()
                print(end3-start3, 'message timing')
                print(s)
                start1 = time.time()
                if message == 'F':
                    # message2_split = message2.split("'")
                    message2_split = message2.split(";")
                    message3_split = [e[3:] for e in message2_split]
                    message4 = pd.Series(message3_split)

                    if message4[0] in tickers:
                        df_fills = df_fills.append(message4, ignore_index=True)
                        print('fill')
                end1 = time.time()
                print(end1-start1)
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                break              



counter = threading.Thread(target = counter)
zmq_loop = zmq_thread('Start_ZMQ')
#%%


counter.start()
zmq_loop.start()
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't realize that ZMQ typical recv_string is by default blocking. So I did this

```
               message = socket.recv_string(flags = zmq.NOBLOCK)
               message2 = socket.recv_string(flags = zmq.NOBLOCK)               
           except zmq.ZMQError as e:               
               if e.errno == zmq.EAGAIN:
                    pass             
           else:     
                if message == 'ABA_BB':
                   message2_split = message2.split(";")
                   message3_split = [e[3:] for e in message2_split]
                   message4 = pd.Series(message3_split)
                   #print(message4)
                   if message4[2] == '300':                        
                       df_signal = df_signal.append(message4, ignore_index=True)               
                       print('Signal Appended')
```